# Invalid command \"/bin/sh\": file not found

Tags: docker, dockerfile, google-cloud-build

I have a Dockerfile with

```
CMD exec gunicorn --bind 8080 --workers 1 --threads 8 --timeout 0 app:app
```

which fails with error: `Invalid command \"/bin/sh\": file not found`

but the same command runs like this:

```
RUN gunicorn --bind 8080 --workers 1 --threads 8 --timeout 0 app:app
```

What could be wrong?

**Update:** The problem starts when I have these two lines added:
`ENV APP_HOME /app` and `WORKDIR $APP_HOME`

Dockerfile:

```
# Dockerfile
FROM penguicky/docker-python3-opencv

ENV APP_HOME /app
WORKDIR $APP_HOME

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y libsm6 libxext6 libxrender-dev
RUN pip3 install Flask gunicorn
RUN pip3 install opencv-contrib-python

EXPOSE 8080

#RUN echo $CV_VERSION

COPY . ./

CMD exec gunicorn --bind 8080 --workers 1 --threads 8 --timeout 0 app:app
```

**Update**

I tried using this way:

```
CMD ["gunicorn", "--bind", "8080", "--workers", "1" ,"--threads", "8", "--timeout", "0" ,"app:app"]
```

now I get this:

```
2020-06-02 22:03:27.511 EEST[2020-06-02 19:03:27 +0000] [1] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
2020-06-02 22:03:27.513 EEST[2020-06-02 19:03:27 +0000] [1] [ERROR] Invalid address: ('8080', 8000)
```

**Update2:**

So it works by this:

```
CMD ["gunicorn", "--bind", "0.0.0.0:8080", "--workers", "1" ,"--threads", "8", "--timeout", "0" ,"app:app"]
```

But I don't know the explanation why it works like this.

Comment: Can you include your entire Dockerfile in the question?  Do you have an `ENTRYPOINT` line?  Is that the entire error message?

Comment: What OS are you using, is it windows and you are using docker desktop? and you tried to change the Docker container to run Windows containers from Linux containers?

Comment: Is this a multi-stage build?

Comment: @DavidMaze added Dockerfile. is not a multi stage build.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this error. Can you try rebuilding the image with `docker build --no-cache ...` ?

Comment: @jakub I added more details. This runs in Google Cloud Run and it's built by Cloud Build.

Comment: What part of "why it works" is unclear, specifically?

Comment: I mean, `--bind 0.0.0.0:8080` works and `--bind 8080` doesn't because you can't bind just to a port and not an address.

Comment: I can't reproduce this either. The container definitely has `/bin/sh` so I deleted my previous answer.

Comment: Well, yes, it has `/bin/sh`, but that doesn't mean it has a file named `"/bin/sh"` with the quotes as part of the name.

Comment: @hmm your answer lead me to the working solution. You can put back the answer.

Comment: @Pentium10 Are you sure this is the exact Dockerfile that led to the /bin/sh error?

Comment: Yes, I am sure. It was really weird, that's why I posted here.

Comment: Can you go back and reproduce that again now? Once you have it reproducing the original issue described in the title, how about with a simpler command, like `CMD echo hello world`?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I tried `CMD echo hello world`. It returns the same issue `error: "Invalid command \"/bin/sh\": file not found"`

Comment: Good -- then you can build a more truly minimal [mre], and thus ask a more focused question that doesn't get answers talking about gunicorn that aren't relevant to the title.

Comment: f/e, do you still get the same problem with only two lines, `FROM penguicky/docker-python3-opencv` and `CMD echo hello world`? Then trim the question down, to include nothing but.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy that works, but when I add `ENV APP_HOME /app` and `WORKDIR $APP_HOME` it gives the error.

Comment: Can you provide the Dockerfile (or source repo) for the base image, penguicky/docker-python3-opencv. The output of docker history on that image would also help.

Comment: Ahh! Does `/app` exist? If it does, does `WORKDIR /app` succeed (implying that the desired expansion just doesn't take place)? I could very much believe that it's not the `execve()` of `/bin/sh` that's failing, but a `chdir()` before it, and just sloppy error reporting (adding the quotes where they don't belong, and not being specific about the failed syscall) in Docker's code.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy `WORKDIR` will create a directory if it doesn't exist.

Comment: @BMitch I don't have access to the docker image. I was looking for a Docker image of OpenCV 4.3 and Python and found that.

Comment: Similar to others, I cannot reproduce your issue. This is likely related to your build and run environment, and not the Dockerfile you are building. I'd recommend providing details on how others can recreate your environment.

Comment: I abandoned the source and using a new source, and that works fine. `borda/docker_python-opencv-ffmpeg`. the build was on Google Cloud Build and executed on Cloud Run.

Answer (score 0):

If you check the `--bind` flag for `gunicorn`, it's mentioned as 
Specify a server socket to bind. Server sockets can be any of `${HOST}`, `${HOST}:${PORT}`, `fd://${FD}`, or `unix:${PATH}`. An `IP` is a valid `${HOST}`

And according to above mentioned flag, you need to mention the whole IP while specifying that flag.

This is **NOT** working as only `8080` port is mentioned.

```
CMD ["gunicorn", "--bind", "8080", "--workers", "1" ,"--threads", "8", "--timeout", "0" ,"app:app"]
```

Below 1 works, because whole `IP` is mentioned.

```
CMD ["gunicorn", "--bind", "0.0.0.0:8080", "--workers", "1" ,"--threads", "8", "--timeout", "0" ,"app:app"]
```

> Ref:- https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/run.html

Comment: `$(anything)` is a variable reference in makefile, but not bash, where it needs to be `${anything}`. That said, this doesn't at all address the titular question about `\"/bin/sh\"`

Answer (score 0):

According to the [CMD instruction documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd) it has three forms:

- `CMD ["executable","param1","param2"]` (exec form, this is the preferred form)
- `CMD ["param1","param2"]` (as default parameters to ENTRYPOINT)
- `CMD command param1 param2` (shell form)

So regarding your line of code:

```
CMD exec gunicorn --bind 8080 --workers 1 --threads 8 --timeout 0 app:app
```

It would be the "third form" of the CMD instruction, that tries to run the "`exec`" executable and sends `gunicorn` as a parameter which is not what you would try to achieve. You can try to run it as the shell form:

```
CMD gunicorn --bind :8080 --workers 1 --threads 8 --timeout 0 app:app
```

Please note that I changed `--bind 8080` to `--bind :8080` which I'm going to explain next.

In the second part of your post you're talking about the "exec" form of the CMD instruction (first on the list):

```
CMD ["gunicorn", "--bind", "8080", "--workers", "1" ,"--threads", "8", "--timeout", "0" ,"app:app"]
```

Which executes correctly but has some issues with the port, as nischay already pointed, can be achieved in two ways:

1- By adding the IP address for example the loopback "`127.0.0.1:8080`"

```
CMD ["gunicorn", "--bind", "127.0.0.1:8080", "--workers", "1" ,"--threads", "8", "--timeout", "0" ,"app:app"]
```

2- By adding the ":" before the port as pointed in [these examples](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/run.html)

```
CMD ["gunicorn", "--bind", ":8080", "--workers", "1" ,"--threads", "8", "--timeout", "0" ,"app:app"]
```

Reference to the bind option:

```
-b BIND, --bind=BIND - Specify a server socket to bind. Server sockets can be any of $(HOST), $(HOST):$(PORT), fd://$(FD), or unix:$(PATH). An IP is a valid $(HOST).
```

Comment: This doesn't explain why `/bin/sh` is available in the base image, but not after `WORKDIR` is set to `/app`.